# Text added with innerHTML when checkbox is checked not removing when unchecked

Tags: javascript

When you check the checkbox I am trying to make the text 'Yes, I like F1' appear in the div with the id="print-f1", which is working.

However the text doesn't **disappear** when you uncheck the checkbox.

Also I noticed if I set the checkbox by default to checked in the HTML, it doesn't load the page with 'Yes, I like F1' adding to the id="print-f1" div either.

I am not using `innerHTML = '';` to remove the text because [I read using `removeChild` is much more efficient](https://coderwall.com/p/nygghw/don-t-use-innerhtml-to-empty-dom-elements).

I am also adding whatever name is entered inside the input into the first grey div with the id="print-name" that part is working.

https://jsfiddle.net/r8qbfdmy/

JS

```
function myForm() {
  var nameForm = document.forms.nameform;
  var printF1 = document.getElementById('print-f1');

  nameForm.name.onkeyup = function() {
    document.getElementById('print-name').innerHTML = nameForm.name.value;
  };

  nameForm.likef1.addEventListener("focus", printF1func)

  function printF1func() {
    if (printF1.checked === false) {
      while (printF1.firstChild) printF1.removeChild(printF1.firstChild);
    } else {
      printF1.innerHTML = nameForm.likef1.value;
    };
  };

};
myForm();
```

HTML

```
<form name="nameform">
  <input name="name" class="form__input rounded-4" placeholder="Enter your name">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="likef1" value="Yes, I like F1"> Do you like F1?
  </label>
  <div id="print-name" class="rounded-4"></div>
  <div id="print-f1" class="rounded-4"></div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.rounded-4 {
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.form__input {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #989898;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #989898;
  padding: 0 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  margin: 20px;
}

#print-name {
  background-color: #989898;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

#print-f1 {
  background-color: #989898;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: is there a reason why you're using the focus event instead of change?

Comment: @devlincarnate I'm just learning JavaScript; if using focus is wrong it's because I'm not fully aware of all options yet :) my thinking was I want to text to appear when the checkbox is checked so when it's focused on, but I guess that was wrong?

Comment: you want the text to appear when the checkbox changes, or is clicked

Comment: $('#divID').click(function() {
        ...do stuff here...
    });
is a more elegant way to handle click triggers, IMO.

Comment: @8protons - how very Jquery-ish of you ;)

Comment: @devlincarnate lol I'm actually VERY  new to JS/jQuery (got thrust into it for the first time at work a few weeks ago) so if that's a stupid suggestion on my part, please let me know haha

Comment: @8protons - not stupid, but since the OP has given pure JavaScript code, it's an assumption that JQuery is an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this...

```
nameForm.likef1.addEventListener("focus", printF1func)

function printF1func() {
    if (printF1.checked === false) {
        while (printF1.firstChild) printF1.removeChild(printF1.firstChild);
    } else {
        printF1.innerHTML = nameForm.likef1.value;
    };
};
```

... with this...

```
nameForm.likef1.addEventListener("change", printF1func);

function printF1func() {
    if (nameForm.likef1.checked) {
        printF1.innerHTML = nameForm.likef1.value;
    } else {
        printF1.innerHTML = '';
    }
};
```

... and it should work fine.

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/r8qbfdmy/4/) for a demo.

---

#### Note :

In this particular case, I seriously doubt you'll get much of a performance gain (if any at all) when using `printF1.removeChild(printF1.firstChild);` instead of `printF1.innerHTML = '';`

If you insist on using `printF1.removeChild(printF1.firstChild);`, however, note that you can drop the while loop, because `printF1` will always have exactly one child every time it is executed :

```
nameForm.likef1.addEventListener("change", printF1func);

function printF1func() {
    if (nameForm.likef1.checked) {
        printF1.innerHTML = nameForm.likef1.value;
    } else {
        printF1.removeChild(printF1.firstChild);
    }
};
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/r8qbfdmy/7/) for a demo.

Comment: Thanks @JohnSlegers nice and clear before and after I can see my mistakes now. I used your changes, but I substituted innerHTML = ' '; for the removeChild line I mentioned in my question, works great! I hadn't tried "change" for the EventListener

Comment: @GoldenGonaz : I updated my answer to address your use of `printF1.removeChild(printF1.firstChild);`

Comment: Thanks for the edit, interesting to hear and also for slimming down the removeChild to what was needed. I am just practising doing different things with JavaScript as I begin to learn, I wanted to keep in the habit of using the "most efficient" methods so when it comes to using them when they would make a difference they're second nature. I understand though in this case it's really making no difference

Comment: @GoldenGonaz : Ever tried "code golfing"? For those people who genuinely enjoy tweaking their code, "code golfing" is a fun and challenging way to learn about all kinds of crazy programming tricks and can get very addictive once you really get really into it. See eg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf, https://github.com/jed/140bytes/wiki/Byte-saving-techniques, http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/, http://www.phpgolf.org/, http://regex.alf.nu/ & http://js1k.com/ for a diverse range of resources related to "code golfing" ;-)

Comment: I've never tried, just reading the wiki now it sounds great! Thanks I've been looking for anything I can that might help me develop further

Comment: @GoldenGonaz : Note that "code golfing" doesn't teach you how to write the best code in terms of either performance or readability, as it focuses exclusively on the number of bytes used. So you can't use it for that. It does, however, provide you a conveniently entertaining way to learn and get familiar with some of the most esoteric programming techniques around.